# JQuery XML option node

Tags: jquery, xml

I am having an issue with parsing XML with JQuery when there is a node with an option node

```
<preferences><dashboard>
<report id="si_pg_vw" order="0">
  <header>
    <data>
      <option type="reportname" value="Page View"/>
    </data>
  </header>
</report>
```

the following code in firebug returns no children

```
$reportElement.find("data")[0]
```

however if I change option to any other value ("option2", "test" etc) then the line above returns one child which is correct.

Am I missing something or is there a bug?

Comment: A few things: Are the `preferences` and `dashboard` tags correctly closed in the XML? What are you assigning to the variable `$reportElement`? Why are you using indexing into the data results rather than iterating over them?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this has to do with the HTML option tag need to be a child of the select tag.

Make sure that the content-type of the response is 'text/xml'. This will probably instruct jQuery to parse the response as xml and not html, thus properly recognizing the option tag.

Comment: Unfortunately this is coming from the server, and other applications depend on this node being "option".

Comment: See my edited answer. I believe you need to set the content type header.

Answer (score 1):

```
$reportElement.find("data")[0]
```

will not work. Try

```
$reportElement.find("data:first")
```

OR

```
$reportElement.find("data:eq(0)")
```

etc

Also, you are not closing 'dashboard' and 'preferences' in your example.

This is the complete example;

```
var myXML = <preferences>
              <dashboard>
                 <report id="si_pg_vw" order="0">
                    <header>
                      <data>
                         <option type="reportname" value="Page View"/>
                      </data>
                    </header>
                </report>
             </dashboard>
           </preferences>

myXML = jQuery(myXML);
myXML.find('data option:first');
//OR
myXML.find('data option:eq(0)');
//OR
myXML.find('data option').each(function(){ window.console.log(this) });
```

etc